# open a flexipage from code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to open a flexipage (Lightning App Builder Page) from code?
I tried the new lightning:navigate (code below) but no luck.

My aim is to implement a Lightning override component which runs a callout and then displays a record page with related lists

(As fyi: I need to show related lists, thus I have to use a flexipage because there is no way to add the related lists in a component)

```
<!-- component.cmp -->
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
<lightning:button label="Nav" onclick="{!c.navigateToFlexipage}" />
</aura:component>


// controller.js
({
    navigateToFlexipage : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var navService = cmp.find("navService");
    var pageReference = {
            "type": "standard__component",
            "attributes": {
                "componentName": "c__myFlexipage"    
            },    
            "state": {}
        };

        navService.navigate(pageReference);    
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain your flow little more clear or what exactly your trying to achieve. Because if you have record Id you can use force:navigateToSobject to go the record detail page!

Comment: @RajeshVarmaMudunuri with summer 18, the preferred method is to use `lightning:navigation`. As for @Etienne, why dont you just use the `standard__recordPage` with `recordId` attributes?

Comment: @RajeshVarmaMudunuri Oh my how did I not see that. I tried standard_object, standard_navItem etc etc, damn! You just made me so happy. thank you!

Comment: @Etienne glad to i was able to help you.

Comment: The problem remains :(       The problem is that standard_*anything* causes an infinite loop.  What happens is this Lightning component is set as the view Override for Case.  When you open a Case the Lightning component then opens itself, infinitely.